# Работа c syscall Golang

Tags: winapi, golang, syscall

Пожалуйста помогите, не могу никак разобратся с syscall. WinAPI функции знаю ибо работал уже с ними (С более чем 25 WMI классами и т.д), но вот как работать с syscall с Golang что куда подставлять какие значение, где нули где единицы... непонятно совсем. Кто мог бы подсказать работу с сисколом например `RemoveDirectoryA`, расписать поподробнее или подсказать статьи желательно на русском языке, очень буду бдагодарен.

Comment: Чем `os.Remove` и `os.RemoveAll` не устраивают? Прямое использование системных вызовов ведёт к непереносимости кода.

Comment: Ничем, хочу поработать с сисколами. То что приведет не к кроссплатформенности это и дураку понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Специально ради вас поставил виртуалку с Виндовс-10. Вот пример с `RemoveDirectoryA`:

```golang
if len(os.Args) < 2 {
    log.Fatal("provide a path")
}

enc := charmap.Windows1252.NewEncoder()
utfPath := os.Args[1]
path, err := enc.Bytes([]byte(utfPath))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

modkernel32 := syscall.NewLazyDLL("Kernel32.dll")
removeDirectoryA := modkernel32.NewProc("RemoveDirectoryA")
r1, _, errno := syscall.Syscall(removeDirectoryA.Addr(), 1, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&path[0])), 0, 0)
if r1 == 0 {
    log.Fatal(errno.Error())
}
```

Подразумевается, что из консоли программа получает ЮТФ-8. Далее перекодировка в АНСИ, подгрузка динамической библиотеки и процедуры из неё. В конце собственно вызов.

Вызов состоит из адреса процедуры, числа аргументов (1), собственно аргумента, и проставления неиспользуемых аргументов в 0. В документации написано, что функция возвращает отличное от нуля значение в случае успеха, поэтому пишем ошибку, если оно не нуль.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я ещё бы хотел узнать что значат все эти 1, 0, 0 в аргументах к сисколу? Нигде не могу найти

Comment: Это всё описано в документации. Добавил ещё один абзац в ответ.